# Confusion about returning the address of an object

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I have the following code (some code removed to strip it to the essentials; the couple methods/attributes used should be self explanatory):

```
void testApp::togglePalette(){
    GraphicalEntity* palette= this->getEntityByName("palette-picker");
    cerr << palette << endl;
}

GraphicalEntity* testApp::getEntityByName(string name){
    list<GraphicalEntity*>::iterator j;
    for(j=screenEntities.begin(); j!=screenEntities.end();++j){
        if ((*j)->getTypetag() == name){
            cerr << *j << endl;
            return *j;
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
0x54bda0
0
```

I'm confused- why isn't `palette` in `togglePalette()` equal to the address returned from `getEntityByName` (so 0x54bda0 in the current case), but to `0`?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** As Fred pointed out in one of his comments, it was indeed an issue of the compiler being confused by the code reaching the end of the function without returning anything.

Adding:

```
return (GraphicalEntity*) NULL;
```

at the end of my `getEntityByName` method solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

I'm still confused by why the method would return `0` even if the object is found (as in the way I implement my code, it is known that there will always be something found) though- any explanation on that would be more than welcome!

Comment: Yes, that is literally what my 2 functions contain, with comments removed. `GraphicalEntity` objects have a `typetag` attribute of type `std::string` which is accessed by `getTypetag()`, and `screenEntities` is an attribute of the testApp class of type `list<GraphicalEntity*>`. The object that is pointed to by `0x54bda0` here is of a class that is a daughter of `GraphicalEntity`.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if no GraphicalEntity has a type tag equals to name? Your posted code reaches the end of the function without returning anything, maybe that's what confuses the compiler.

Comment: Right now I haven't implemented the "no typetag behavior" yet as in my case, I am certain that there will be an object with the typetag "palette-picker". I do get a compiler warning, but I wouldn't expect it to cause that issue.

Comment: @quamrana: If that was the case, it wouldn't write the first line.

Comment: @Guillaume: Making such assumptions (when you _are_ having an issue) is silly. Write `return 0;` at the end of the function.

Comment: Make a testcase. We cannot determine what is wrong as we don't even know what your input looks like.

Comment: Tomalak: that was indeed the issue- thanks for answering! However, I'm missing a C++ subtlety here- why would the method return 0 although there is an object found? (as evidenced by the first output line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on my comment, here's a more complete answer.

There is a path in your `testApp::getEntityByName()` method where control exits the method without returning a value. Depending on your compiler, architecture and calling convention, this could result in machine code that doesn't work *even if your flow never goes through the erroneous path*.

Depending on the calling convention, it is either the caller or the called method's responsibility to clean up the stack before or after the method returns. The return value, and where it is allocated in memory, is part of that convention, and a compiler expects a function to always return the same type no matter what the control flow within the function is. Because of that, it can optimize some methods by rearranging some stuff and generating specific clean-up code to clean restore the stack according to the calling convention. In any case, the missing return value can mess up that optimization or clean-up because it violates what the compiler took for granted when it processed your code, i.e. that every path returned a pointer to a `GraphicalEntity` object. Failing that assumption corrupted the stack or its content, and you ended up with a NULL pointer (it might as well have crashed or done just about anything else, it's all part of *undefined behavior*).

Answer (score 0):

It could happened if screenEntities is accessed via another thread so the "pallette-picker" has been removed or modified. Then getEntityByName function will return NULL in debug mode.